# Assigning Outlook Appointment recurrence type from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to Add an Appointment in Outlook by code. There is a attribute called "GetRecurrencePattern().RecurrenceType" for the "Outlook.AppointmentItem" object. When I am trying to set this attribute to "OlRecurrenceType.olRecursDaily" it automatically gets converted to "OlRecurrenceType.olRecursWeekly".

Here is my code:

```
       Outlook.AppointmentItem oMeet;
Meeting Meet;
Hashtable htrecc = GetReccuranceTable(strRec);
  if (Meet.recctype.Substring(0, 3) == "day")
  {
     oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().RecurrenceType = OlRecurrenceType.olRecursDaily;
    OlRecurrenceType pattern2 = oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().RecurrenceType;
     string rectype = pattern2.ToString();
     oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().Interval = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Interval"]);
     if (string.Equals("no", htrecc["Occurence"]))
         oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().NoEndDate = true;
     else
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(htrecc["Occurence"])))
              oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().Occurrences = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Occurence"]);
          else
              oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern().PatternEndDate = Meet.EndTime;
    }
```

The string "rectype" returns a value "**olRecursWeekly**"
Please Suggest if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried saving your AppointmentItem after you set its RecurrenceType? `oMeet.Save()` before you try to retrieve the RecurrenceType.

Comment: No , oMeet.Save() is called after all the attributes have been assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call GetRecurrencePattern(), you get back a brand new RecurrentPattern COM object. Do not call GetRecurrencePattern() every time - call it once, cache the value, and use it everywhere in your code

```
 Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = oMeet.GetRecurrencePattern();
 pattern.RecurrenceType = OlRecurrenceType.olRecursDaily;
    OlRecurrenceType pattern2 = pattern.RecurrenceType;
     string rectype = pattern2.ToString();
     pattern.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Interval"]);
     if (string.Equals("no", htrecc["Occurence"]))
         pattern.NoEndDate = true;
     else
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(htrecc["Occurence"])))
              pattern.Occurrences = Convert.ToInt32(htrecc["Occurence"]);
          else
              pattern.PatternEndDate = Meet.EndTime;
```